# How to decode a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, perl, json

On the server side do I have 2 hashes I encode into JSON strings like so

```
my $j = JSON->new;
$j = $j->utf8;

my $data;
$data->{users}  = $j->encode(\%user_result);
$data->{owners} = $j->encode(\%owner_result);
$json_string    = to_json($data);

print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print $json_string;
```

On the client side I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('form').live('submit', function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/cgi-bin/ajax_confirm.pl",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",

        data: $(this).serialize(),

        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        $('div#create_result').text("responseText: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText +
                        ", textStatus: " + textStatus +
                        ", errorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        },

        success: function(result){
        if (result.error) {
            $('div#create_result').text("result.error: " + result.error);
            $('div#create_result').addClass("error");
        } else { // perl script says everything is okay

            var users  = result.users;
            var owners = result.owners;
...
```

`users` contains

```
{"ss":"Sandra Schlichting","fn":"Full name"}
```

but it is not an array. When I use `$.each()` it takes on character at a time.

**Problem**

How do I turn it into an array, so I can use

```
function makeTable(users) {
    var result = '<table>\n<tr><td>Initials</td><td>Full Name</td></tr>\n';
    $.each(users, function(index, value) {
        result += '<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td>' + value + '</td></tr>\n';
    });
    result += '</table>';
    return (result);
}
```

which should produce

```
Initials    Full Name
ss  Sandra Schlichting
fn  Full name
```

Comment: You should leave a comment for the person who wrote that jQuery code in your last question. Not open a new question, it just causes bad fragmentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include array content in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028241/how-to-include-array-content-in-html)

Comment: @Gary Green : I thought about that, but he solved the question to perfection, so I figured it would be off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use jQuery.getJSON() as mentioned at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/.

There is also $.parseJSON() method to parse string to json if you want to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to turn it into an array. According to the [jQuery.each() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) it takes both arrays or objects and JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript.

Edit: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocorreia/s5UrZ/2/

Comment: Why does this work? What does `var res = makeTable(my); \n document.write(res);` do?

Comment: it declares a variable and assigns the return value of your makeTable function and then writes it to the html document. the variable 'my' supplied to the function contains the json object you decribed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JSON parser created by douglas crockford:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

include the `json2.js` in your page, the you can do:

```
var object = JSON.parse(string);
```

Then you can use it as an array.

Comment: You could also use the build-in JSON parser: `$.parseJSON(data)`

Answer (score 0):

you can use for in statement

```
var index = 0;
for(user in users){
  result += '<tr><td>' + index + '</td><td>' + user['fn'] + '</td></tr>\n';
index++;
}
```