# parsing json file in javascript who's url extension is not .json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to parse json data from url which contain json data, but its extension is not .json

When I try to request response url using below code it make ajax request with 200 status code.

But I try with other url containing same data with .json extension, it works.

Here is my javascript code

```
var url='http://jsonurl.com/jsondata';
jQuery.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(d){
      jQuery.each(d,function(i){
       console.log(i);
    });
  }
});
```

So I want solution to parse json content of file in javascript or in jquery, which dont have .json extension but contain json data .

Comment: Did you validate what the URL returns? I don't believe the extension matters for jQuery.

Comment: The file extension doesn't matter, all that matters is that the JSON in the file is valid, though a `Content-type: application/json` couldn't hurt.

Comment: this is the url I m trying to parse: http://api.tweetmixx.com/topics/318/tweeters

Comment: That URL returns the correct content-type already, things should Just Work.

Comment: Have a look at my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030388/how-to-decode-a-json-string/6030520#6030520

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the exact problem, after discussion with support team of API. 
Actually the problem is with content type. They implemented some cache system for that json data, and when my script make request to API url, it send that json data and creates its cache and that cache remain active for some time. If my script create same request, then that json data served from cache who's content type is not json.

Now they are working on this issue.

BTW thanks Peter for help. :)

Answer (score 2):

CORRECTION: now seen your example url above and the content type is correct so that was a bit of a red herring.

The extension does not matter.
But the URL you are calling will need to return the correct content type which would be `application/json` Having said that our app uses `text/javascript` which works as I believe the browsers are a bit lenient.

So in my case I call a JSP getJSON.jsp that sets it's content type like this

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/javascript; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

I am guessing that when you use the .json extention the server is returning with the correct type but your other extensions will not.