# Codeigniter / PHP/ convert Object to JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

I cannot fully understand what I have below and I need to convert it to JSON.

My guess is I have an array of 16 starting from 0 to 15.  Item 0 is an object by ["id"]=>"1", ["ip_address"]=>"127.0.0.3", etc looks like an associative array.  Confused.

Second question when I decode($abovearray) I get something but doesn't look like JSON!  Any help much appreciated.

Here is a sample of my array output that I need to convert to JSON.

```
array(16) {
           [0]=> object(stdClass)#31 (25) {
              ["id"]=> string(1) "1"
              ["ip_address"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.3"
              ["username"]=> string(13) "administrator"
              [~snip~]
              }
           [1]=> object(stdClass)#33 (25) {
              ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
              ["ip_address"]=> string(15) "111.111.111.201"
              ["username"]=> string(0) ""
              [~snip~]
              }
     ...}
```

Comment: what you have is an array of objects ( not array of strings)

Comment: I see two observations, but no clear questions.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
$json = json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
echo $json;
```

Answer (score 0):

On controller

```
public function test() {
    $data = array();

    $data[] = array(
        'id' => '1',
        'ip_address' => "127.0.0.3",
        'username' => 'administrator'
    );

    $data[] = array(
        'id' => '2',
        'ip_address' => "111.111.111.201",
        'username' => ''
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Should out put

```
[{"id":"1","ip_address":"127.0.0.3","username":"administrator"},{"id":"2","ip_address":"111.111.111.201","username":""}]

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#commit').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax
    ({ 
    type: 'get',
    url: "<?php echo base_url('welcome/test');?>",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response)
    {
       alert(response['username']) // you may need to use the jquery each function

      https://api.jquery.com/each/

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It look like data in view for js but in php use this 
**in PHP**

```
  $jsonEncode  =  json_encode($array);
```

**in JS** 
[How to decode a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030388/how-to-decode-a-json-strings)